# any solution for operating Hyperlink included in MySQL database at laravel blade?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

There are 2000 rows in MySQL database with Description column which has some text and URLs included.

If there are URLs only 1 or 2, I can easily make additional column(s) to add but number of URLs are many and URLs numbers are different each row.

Is there any PHP function for automatically detect HTML Links - The target Attribute instead of writing `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>` every value?

If there is no solution, it takes so long to add HTML Links - The target Attribute on 2000 values.

I am using Laravel 5.3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 {!! $yourVar !!}
```

String will auto escape when you perform {{ }}

Check on picture

[image]

[image]